# Handler.Callback - prefer composition over inheritance while instantiating from Handler

Tags: android, handler

I wonder the use of Handler.Callback . I cannot find any detailed information on the web. In the resource below :
http://files.dcarl.me/books/First_Collection_Programming_Books/Asynchronous%20Android%20%5BeBook%5D.pdf
it is said that :

> We can prefer composition over inheritance by passing an instance of
>   Handler.Callback during Handler construction.

The example on the resource is the following :

```
public static class SpeakHandler extends Handler {
    public static final int SAY_HELLO = 0;
    public static final int SAY_BYE = 1;
    public SpeakHandler(Callback callback) {
        super(callback);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
            case SAY_HELLO:
                sayWord("hello"); break;
            case SAY_BYE:
                sayWord("goodbye"); break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    private void sayWord(String word) { … }
}
public static class Speaker implements Handler.Callback {
    public static final int SAY_WORD = 2;
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == SAY_WORD) {
            sayWord((String)msg.obj);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void sayWord(String word) { … }
}
Handler h = new SpeakHandler(new Speaker());
h.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, Speaker.SAY_WORD, "!?"));
```

Why i need the Handler.Callback in the above code? I can do the same thing as the following :

```
    public static class SpeakHandler extends Handler {
    public static final int SAY_HELLO = 0;
    public static final int SAY_BYE = 1;
    public static final int SAY_WORD = 2;
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
            case SAY_HELLO:
                sayWord("hello"); break;
            case SAY_BYE:
                sayWord("goodbye"); break;
            case SAY_WORD:
                sayWord((String)msg.obj); break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    private void sayWord(String word) { … }
}
```

What is Handler.Callback ? In the official documentation it is said that

> Callback interface you can use when instantiating a Handler to avoid
>   having to implement your own subclass of Handler.
>   I didn't understand what it means..

Comment: A long discussion on this can be found on the Software Enginnering Stackexchange here:

http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from

Comment: In a general sense, composition is preferred because it's more extensible as the program grows in size. However, it's often spouted as programming dogma than an actual hard rule. I would say that a `Handler` is not a `Speaker`, and a `Speaker` is not a `Handler`, so it wouldn't make logical sense to combine the two as one entity.

Comment: @DeeV , what is Handler.Callback ?